# Mesos kafka-scheduler registration

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos

I have finished a framework of kafka-mesos using the API via teardown method. The problem is that when I want to deploy again kafka-scheduler is taking the old frameworkId and it never starts.

```
 I1213 10:57:47.807209  4382 sched.cpp:1171] Got error 'Framework has been removed'
 I1213 10:57:47.807363  4382 sched.cpp:2029] Asked to abort the driver
 I1213 10:57:47.810469  4382 sched.cpp:1217] Aborting framework bafe25fd-69c0-4cf4-a2b7-13d05ba5d92c-0002
```

Any ideas how can I deploy again? In zookeeper I've cleaned all the references to kafka.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but perhaps you need to [remove any old brokers](https://github.com/mesos/kafka#removing-brokers-from-the-cluster)?

Comment: I just restarted mesos master and it worked... but I do not like this solution